# Array items not showing up in jQuery inArray

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array: 5, 10, 15, 20. When I press a button another number is added to the array, making it: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35 (etc.).

Now. I have a function which checks if a number is in that array whenever I press a button. So if that number is 10, and it finds 10 in the array, it returns true. If the number is 30 (new number added to array), and it checks if the number is in the array (which it is), it is as if the new array item has not been added, because the function return false.

This is the code structure is as follows:

```
var check = $.inArray(number, array);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns the *index* of the element. `-1` is synonymous to *not found*, so check if the index is greater than `-1`:

```
var check = $.inArray(number, array) > -1;
```

And from the API:

> Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).

Comment: That is not what I am trying to achieve however. I might have been unclear. What I was trying to say was that if number (30) == inArray (30), return = someNumberHere (or -1 if not found).

Since I have a function that checks if the outcome is not -1, then run a code.

The problem is that it works if no items are added, it is only the new items to the array that it cannot seem to 'find', thus returning -1. If I alert out the array the items DO exist in it, for the record,